# Jest + Formik - Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await

Tags: react-native, jestjs, react-testing-library, formik

I am struggling with `act` errors when it comes to testing my React Native application using `JEST` and `testing-library`.
I have a simple Formik form and I am trying to test if the validation works.

**My screen I am testing:**

```
const SignInScreen: React.FC = () => {
    const { translations } = useContext(LocalizationContext);
    const [signIn, { isLoading, isError }] = useSignInMutation();

    const initialValues: SignInRequest = {
        name: '',
        password: ''
    };

    const validationSchema = Yup.object({
        name: Yup.string()
            .required(translations['required'])
            .max(15, ({max}) => translations.formatString(
                translations['validationNCharOrLess'], { n: max })),
        password: Yup.string()
            .required(translations['required'])
    });

    const handleSubmit = async (values: SignInRequest, formikHelpers: FormikHelpers<SignInRequest>) => {
        await signIn(values)
            .unwrap()
            .catch(e => {
                if ('data' in e && e.data &&
                    'errors' in e.data && e.data.errors)
                {
                    formikHelpers.setErrors(mapErrors(e.data.errors));
                }
            })
    }

    return (
        <SafeAreaView
            testID={tiConfig.SAFE_AREA_VIEW}
            style={{ flex: 1 }}>
            <View
                testID={tiConfig.SIGN_IN_SCREEN}
                style={styles.container}>
                <View>
                    <Text>{translations['signIn']}</Text>
                    <Formik
                        initialValues={initialValues}
                        validationSchema={validationSchema}
                        onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                        {
                            ({ values, errors, handleSubmit, handleChange }) => (
                                <View>
                                    <Input
                                        testID={tiConfig.SIGN_IN_USERNAME_INPUT}
                                        value={values.name}
                                        placeholder={translations['username']}
                                        onChangeText={handleChange('name')}
                                        errorMessage={errors.name} />
                                    <Input
                                        testID={tiConfig.SIGN_IN_PASSWORD_INPUT}
                                        value={values.password}
                                        placeholder={translations['password']}
                                        onChangeText={handleChange('password')}
                                        errorMessage={errors.password}
                                        secureTextEntry />
                                    {
                                        isError ?
                                            <View>
                                                <Text testID={tiConfig.SIGN_IN_SERVER_ERROR}>
                                                    { translations['somethingWentWrongTryAgainLater'] }
                                                </Text>
                                            </View>
                                            : null
                                    }
                                    <Button
                                        testID={tiConfig.SIGN_IN_SUBMIT}
                                        title={translations['signIn']}
                                        onPress={handleSubmit}
                                        loading={isLoading} />
                                </View>
                            )
                        }
                    </Formik>
                </View>
            </View>
        </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
```

**My test:**

```
// tiConfig is a json with my test id constants
test.only("Sign in username field validates correctly", async () => {
    const component = render(<SignInScreen />);

    const usernameInput = await component.findByTestId(tiConfig.SIGN_IN_USERNAME_INPUT);   
    // A bit weird way to find the error text with a nesting but it works for now
    const errorMessage = usernameInput
        .parent!.parent!.parent!.parent!.parent!.parent!.findByType(Text);
    const submit = component.getByTestId(tiConfig.SIGN_IN_SUBMIT);

    fireEvent.press(submit);
    await waitFor(() => expect(errorMessage.props.children).toBe(translations.required));
    fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, "username");
    await waitFor(() => expect(errorMessage).toBeEmpty());
    fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, "toolongusernameshouldntbeallowed");
    await waitFor(() => expect(errorMessage).not.toBeEmpty());
});
```

**Warning:**

```
Warning: You called act(async () => ...) without await. This could lead to unexpected testing behaviour, interleaving multiple act calls and mixing their scopes. You should - await act(async () => ...);

      at registerError (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:172:15)
      at errorImpl (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:58:22)
      at console.Object.<anonymous>.console.error (node_modules/react-native/Libraries/LogBox/LogBox.js:32:14)
      at printWarning (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:68:30)
      at error (node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:44:5)
      at node_modules/react-test-renderer/cjs/react-test-renderer.development.js:15297:13
      at tryCallOne (node_modules/promise/lib/core.js:37:12)
```

I get this warning **3 times**
Without `waitFor` my test doesn't pass as all of the `expect` need to be awaited. I tried to wrap `fireEvent`s in `act` as well, but according to few blog posts from Kent C. Dodds we shouldn't wrap `fireEvent` in `act` so although the test passes I still get the warnings.
Any ideas how I can fix this?

Answer (score 0):

I faced similar issues. Wrapping fireEvent with `await waitFor` did the trick for me. So, when you call `fireEvent.changeText` make sure to wrap it with `await waitFor`

In your case,

```
test.only("Sign in username field validates correctly", async () => {
    ... Other test suites

    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, 'username');
    });

    await waitFor(() => {
      fireEvent.changeText(usernameInput, 'toolongusernameshouldntbeallowed');
    });
});
```

Comment: Tried wrapping **only** `await waitFor(() =>)` around the `fireEvent`s. Still getting 3 errors, also tried wrapping both `fireEvent` and `expect` and getting 6 errors. Any other ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Well, wrapping `fireEvent` in `act` actually solved the issue and I am not getting warnings, if has a different answer that would work or explanation why this work I would be delighted to hear it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).